# Flask deploy to heroku errors

Tags: python, heroku

I when i try to open my website https://pomocnikprofesora.herokuapp.com/ its dont work.
This is my logs
I dont know what can i say more but i cant put this question without more normal text.
Any advice and help will be great for me.
Thanks

```
$ heroku logs --tail
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.37.0 to 7.47.3.
2020-11-30T16:12:03.048409+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user rozplochowskipawel9@gmail.com
2020-11-30T16:12:03.048409+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user rozplochowskipawel9@gmail.com
2020-11-30T16:12:03.170216+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user rozplochowskipawel9@gmail.com
2020-11-30T16:12:03.170216+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user rozplochowskipawel9@gmail.com
2020-11-30T16:12:22.236825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-coast-67373.herokuapp.com request_id=49dbe3e9-8b50-49cc-94b0-9ec7fde34228 fwd="31.60.48.45" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-30T16:12:22.983607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-coast-67373.herokuapp.com request_id=4b30a4cb-d870-42eb-9834-b5aaa006c1b5 fwd="31.60.48.45" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-30T16:13:57.834416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=pomoncikprofesora.herokuapp.com request_id=ca16ec59-2bf7-4741-a873-67096832462f fwd="31.60.48.45" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-30T16:16:16.950761+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-30T16:16:16.950764+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951127+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951128+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951411+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951412+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951616+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951902+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951941+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951944+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951944+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951945+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951945+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-30T16:16:16.951949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952070+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952071+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952219+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952220+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952395+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952396+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952520+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952521+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952689+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952897+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.952898+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953149+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953150+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953324+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953325+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953633+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2020-11-30T16:16:16.953634+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2020-11-30T16:16:17.052618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-30T16:16:17.117406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-30T17:01:23.850624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-30T17:01:30.144003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:PomocnikProfesora.py`
2020-11-30T17:01:33.283660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-11-30T17:01:33.291826+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:43889 (4)
2020-11-30T17:01:33.300878+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-30T17:01:33.318087+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:33 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-11-30T17:01:34.497407+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to parse 'PomocnikProfesora.py' as an attribute name or function call.
2020-11-30T17:01:34.498343+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:34 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-11-30T17:01:34.520370+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to parse 'PomocnikProfesora.py' as an attribute name or function call.
2020-11-30T17:01:34.521180+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-30T17:01:34.690436+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-30T17:01:34.690611+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-30 17:01:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2020-11-30T17:01:34.770227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2020-11-30T17:01:34.808969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: you need to show your code for debugging help, see [how to ask a question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is my code https://github.com/pawroz/PomocnikProfesora @bhucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the logs, your app crashed while loading:

```
2020-11-30T16:21:28.904773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
```

The error also says that it is not able to parse the file `PomocnikProfesora.py` :

```
Failed to parse 'PomocnikProfesora.py' as an attribute name or function call
```

1. Check if this file is executing properly or not
2. Also check how you have instantiated gunicorn. If this is the entry point for your app, try this in the Procfile:

   web: gunicorn app:PomocnikProfesora

Comment: Yes your right my Procfile was wrong i had "PomocnikProfesora.py" but still have a errors. What do you mean "Check if this file is executing properly or not"? this project working well at localhost.

Comment: Okay, can you share the error you are facing now? Maybe the heroku logs (last 20 lines)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is crashing because of a failure to parse this file:

```
Failed to parse 'PomocnikProfesora.py' as an attribute name or function call
```

Try fixing that problem and resolving dependencies.